# How can I set up a filter in Synaptic that finds all packages not installed from official repositories?

Tags: ppa, repository, synaptic

The custom filter options in Synaptic are kind of cryptic to me. I know over the last year and a half (I haven't fresh-installed since 10.04) I've installed several .debs and packages from PPAs.

How can I set up a filter in Synaptic that finds just these packages, so that I can downgrade or remove them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually not as hard as I thought it might be - and it's probably quite a valuable filter to have!

First you select which status you want to show. I selected "Installed" amongst a couple of others but that's probably all you need.

[image]

The real nuts and bolts come from the properties screen. In there you can set the origin requirements. All I did was *exclude* anything from `archive.ubuntu.com` (which is the mirror I use). If you're using another mirror, change that string.

[image]

The alternative would be to disable all the PPAs in sources and then look at the local section.

Answer (score 1):

You can tray to find the package you look for by using the Origin button instead off custom filters.